# android.security.KeyStoreException: User authentication required after upgrade to android 8

Tags: java, android, security

After update on android 8 I'm getting **android.security.KeyStoreException: User authentication required** when I'm trying to create new key in order to use it after fingerprint authentication.
Before update to 8, it was working as expected.
This is not happening on every device.

```
  mKeyStore.load(null);

 KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    alias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(userAuthenticationRequired) 
                    .setKeyValidityEnd(calendar.getTime())
                    .setKeySize(keysize)
                    .build();
mKeyPairGenerator.initialize(spec);
 KeyPair keyPair = mKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();//this is the line I'm getting the keystore exception
```

Comment: Did you figure this out at all? Seeing a similar issue, almost entirely on Android 8 on Samsung devices.

Answer (score 1):

We narrowed this issue to S9 Android 8 devices was not secured with PIN, pattern or password.

One solution is to add a ProviderException to the try catch block surrounding generateKeyPair and handle it there.

Alternatively you may use KeyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure() to prevent the key generation.